# Можно ли в тестах pytest/selenium получить более конкретную информацию о ошибке?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

У меня есть функция с проверкой assert

```
    def main_page(self, browser):
        main_page = BasePage(browser)
        main_page.go_to_site()
        search_elements = self.find_elements(Locators.LOCATOR_ELEMENT)
        response = requests.head(browser.current_url)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert len(search_elements) == 30
```

При возникновении ошибки я могу увидеть только сообщение AssertionError

```
    def click_button_collection1(self, browser):
        search_field = self.find_elements(Locators.LOCATOR_COLLECTION)[0]
        search_field.click()
        search_elements = self.find_elements(Locators.LOCATOR_ELEMENT)
        response = requests.head(browser.current_url)
        assert response.status_code == 200
>       assert len(search_elements) == 601
E       AssertionError

search.py:27: AssertionError
```

Есть ли способ получить больше информации об ошибке и обработать ее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что именно вы хотите увидеть? Автоматически никто за вас не разберётся, что именно пошло не так. Единственное, что тут можно по-быстрому сделать - это использовать расширенную форму `assert`. Например:

```
assert response.status_code == 200, f'Сайт вернул код {response.status_code}'
```

Тогда вы увидите не просто ошибку, что проверка не сработала, но и узнаете, какой именно код вернул сайт. В принципе, вы там можете напечатать все интересующие вас переменные, знание содержания которых вам поможет лучше понять происхождение проблемы.

Возможно, есть и какие-то специальные фичи `pytest` для этого, но тут я не в курсе просто.

Comment: Спасибо! Это мне поможет